# Error while processing sampler: 'bzm - Parallel Controller'. java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.lang.ThreadLocal

Tags: jmeter

Error while processing sampler: 'bzm - Parallel Controller'.
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.lang.ThreadLocal this error facing while using bzm parallel controller in jmeter latest version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should review the way you're launching JMeter as it's missing the necessary `--add-opens` argument for the [java.lang](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) package

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) the relevant line looks as follows:

```
--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
```

So the options are in:

1. Either add the above line to your `java` executable arguments
2. Or launch JMeter using [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat) file provided
3. Or downgrade your Java to [version 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/), it is sufficient to run JMeter 5.5 and you won't have to worry about explicitly enabling these modules